# Retrieve array elements from a list of index

Tags: python

I have an array `my_array` containing some tuple data.

I have another array `my_array_values` of same length containing some integer values.

For each unique value of `my_array_values`, I want to retrieve a list of values from `my_array`, that are in the same index as this value in `my_array_values`. Here is my code and the expected behavior :

```
my_array = np.array([('AA','11'),('BB','22'),('CC','33'),('DD','44'),('EE','55'),('FF','66')])
my_array_values = np.array([1,2,3,1,3,2])
my_array_values_unique = np.array([1,2,3])

for v in my_array_values_unique:
    print(np.take(my_array, np.where(my_array_values == v)))
```

Expected behavior :

```
[('AA', '11'), ('DD', '44')]
[('BB', '22'), ('FF', '66')]
[('CC', '33'), ('EE', '55')]
```

But actually, my code gives me the following output:

```
[['AA' '22']]
[['11' '33']]
[['BB' 'CC']]
```

Can someone explain to me how I can get the correct output?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using numpy rather than standard Python lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `take` or `where` at all. Equality check on an array returns a boolean array which is a valid indexing array:

```py
for v in my_array_values_unique:
    print(my_array[my_array_values == v])
```

And this prints:

```
[['AA' '11']
 ['DD' '44']]
[['BB' '22']
 ['FF' '66']]
[['CC' '33']
 ['EE' '55']]
```

---

If `numpy` is not specificly required, this can be easily done using lists as well:

```py
lst = [('AA', '11'), ('BB', '22'), ('CC', '33'), ('DD', '44'), ('EE', '55'), ('FF', '66')]
idxs = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]

for v in set(idxs):
    print([tup for idx, tup in zip(idxs, lst) if idx == v])
```

Gives:

```
[('AA', '11'), ('DD', '44')]
[('BB', '22'), ('FF', '66')]
[('CC', '33'), ('EE', '55')]
```

---

Another, more efficient, way would be to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in order to loop the list once, instead of once for every unique value:

```py
import collections

mapping = collections.defaultdict(list)
for tup, idx in zip(lst, idxs):
    mapping[idx].append(tup)

for lst in mapping.values():
    print(lst)
```

- gives the same result as before

Answer (score 2):

Please use `axis=0` when using `np.take` in this case. By default, it flattens out your array that's why you are getting 'AA' and '22' for case '1'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, If you are using NumPy array, it will return a list of an array within an array, so you won't get any tuple from it, until and unless you manipulate it again